# rm: /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

I keep getting this message:

```
rm: /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path: Permission denied
```

When trying to execute this command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

I'm working on a brand new MacBook Pro with Mavericks OS X 10.9.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, solved it by telling it to install using GCC 4.2

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

and running the following:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247 --verify-downloads 2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
```

The reason for the openssl switch is that I had a problem when updating gems later on.

If you're using the command line tools from Kenneth Reitz, you may also get a permission denied error later on. I had to delete the following dir

```
/usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path
```

I assume this won't be an issue with XCode.